Can not pull integer using variable in google tag manager?
My custom html tag is
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "QAPage",
      "mainEntity": {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "{{QuestionTitle}}",
        "text": "{{QuestionDes}}",
        "answerCount": {{QAnswerCount}},
        "upvoteCount": {{QupvoteCount}},
.........
........

I can pull the values of "{{QuestionTitle}}" "{{QuestionDes}}" which are text format..
But can not pull integer values of {{QAnswerCount}} and {{QupvoteCount}}...
Can not fig out the problem..
ref: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/qapage
I have tried using ""  like "{{QAnswerCount}}"
But both cases give error like
"@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "QAPage",
      "mainEntity": {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "QuestionTitle",
        "text": "Question Description",
        "answerCount": *google_tag_manager["rm"]["183766654"](2)*,
        "upvoteCount": *google_tag_manager["rm"]["183766654"](3)*,
        "datePublished": "May 2, 2024",

`

You should provided the code you are using.

The quotes are missing.
{{QAnswerCount}} -> "{{QAnswerCount}}"
